# laravel validation rule max:value not working with variables

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

i’m a newby in laravel , i’m trying to validate a certain field from my input request using the max:value rule , the thing is that the value is neither a static value nor a field in my request input , its a value that i retrieve from my database and stored in a variable $available , whenever i try ( ‘count’ => required|numeric|max:$available ) the validation always fails on max as if it cannot evaluate that variable $available , however when i try to use a static value which is not the case (e.g ‘count’ => required|numeric|max:5 ) it works just fine , i also tried to merge $available with the input fields of my request before validation using “ $request->merge(['availableCount' =>$availableRoom->count]); “ and then i tried to use the field ‘availableCount’ in my rule instead of the variable (e.g ‘count’ => required|numeric|max:availableCount) the validation never fails and it always proceeds with the controller logic !! what did i do wrong or what am i supposed to do ?! Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B43LJz8WWXD6ak5HaXVqcWtpVzA/view?usp=sharing @Muggles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58249354/pass-dynamic-value-to-laravel-max-validation-rule

Answer (score 1):

A small update if this doesn't work.

Try:

```
'count' => 'required|numeric|max:{$available}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
‘count’ => "required|numeric|max:$available"
```

instead of

```
‘count’ => 'required|numeric|max:$available'
```

When you use single quotes then **$available** is not evaluated so what you pass to validator is literally **max:$available**.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but just in case anyone is needing this

In Laravel 8 this works:

```
'count' => "required|numeric|max:$available"
```

Use Double Quotes instead of single.

Comment: the validation error will be the field is more than $available .. which is not very good for UX